# How to get "local address book" in Name Picker?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

We have a name picker in **Xpages** which should get the values from current server's NAB &  local address book .

Our code to get values from server's NAB is working fine.

But i don't know how to write for "Local Address Book"

i tried with ("") & others for server name , no luck.

Can any one tell me how should i give the server name in dblookup?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with 'local adres book' . Is this the names.nsf on the current server or the names.nsf on the local machine of the current user?

Comment: Are you using XPinc? or plain vanilla Xpages

Comment: @jjtbsomhorst 

names.nsf on the local machine of the current user.

Comment: @TobySamples - no I'm not using Xpinc & sorry i don't know what is "vanilla Xpages ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you're using a standard ("vanilla") version of xpages this means that you're running your code right on a Domino server.  the server however has no chance whatsoever to access some kind of Notes client database - how should this be possible, especially since you don't use a Notes client in the first place. Therefor you need to bring your NAB data to the server.

At first glance I see two options for that:

1. create replicas of the personal NABs in question on that server and modify their ACLs so that they will be accessible from a server side script code
2. make sure you're using an iNotes enabled mail file, and also make sure that you're replicating your personal NAB data into this mailfile (see iNotes documentation if in doubt). Then you should be able to access your personal NAB data through your mailfile. It should contain all of the important views that also are in your personal NAB database.